# How can I remove html elements that are nested into each other?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I have an html structure like this:

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<h1>ah</h1>
<child>
    <p>Haha</p>
    <child>
      <p>Hihi</P>
    </child>
</child>
<child>
<h4>Hello</h4>
</child>
<h3>Hello</h3>
```

Goal:

My Goal is to remove all child tags from the DOM to receive this:

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<h1>ah</h1>
<h3>Hello</h3>
```

What I tried:

```js
const html = document.createElement('div');
//This is the HTML I pasted above.
html.innerHTML = this.item.Body;
let childTags = html.getElementsByTagName('child');

for (let i = 0; i < childTags.length; i++) {
  let childTag = childTags[i];
  childTag.remove();
}

this.item.Body = html.innerHTML;
```

My Problem:

The problem that I am having is that `getElementsByTagName` finds the nested tag that is already removed when I remove the parent child tag, this makes it so the for loop doesn't work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: A snippet only makes sense, when there's something that can be executed and that adds something useful to the question. In this case it would require a "correct" snippet (-> [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets", how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)). Otherwise use simple code blocks.

Comment: _"Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself, and it was embarassingly easy.

I had to make a recursive function.

```js
removeChildComponents() {
const html = document.createElement('div');
html.innerHTML = this.item.Body;

let childTag = html.getElementsByTagName('child');
if (childTag.length > 0) {
        childTag[0].remove();
}

this.item.Body = html.innerHTML;

const recursionHandler = html.getElementsByTagName('child')
if (recursionHandler.length > 0) {
        this.removeChildComponents();
};
};
```

Comment: You created a `removeChildComponents` method and this appears to be only the body of it. Please post the whole method (with the signature) as you are referring it recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Firstly you `getElementsByTagName` that returns an `HTMLCollection` which you convert into an array using `Array.prototype.slice`. Then `forEach` child i.e item in array, you `.remove()` it from DOM.

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('child')).forEach(child => child.remove());
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<h1>ah</h1>
<child>
  <p>Haha</p>
  <child>
    <p>Hihi</p>
  </child>
</child>
<child>
  <h4>Hello</h4>
</child>
<h3>Hello</h3>
```